# programming Pofung UV-82

Tags: united-states, legal, baofeng

As an alternative to the higher priced Motorola portables we use at our volunteer fire department, individuals have purchased several Bao Feng UV-82HP units to carry to monitor dispatch and fire ground traffic while off duty.  All have programmed up easily with CHIRP programming.  Last batch arrived as Bao Feng's new identity, POFUNG.  Look and act similar, but won't transmit on Public Service band.  Am I missing a Basic, Advanced or Other setting for perhaps European or Asian markets?  They seem to work fine on US 2m and 70cm frequencies, but won't transmit on Public Service band.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 8):

Commercially-sold radios that transmit for nearly every purpose other than the amateur service (Part 97) and Industrial, Scientific, and Medical ([ISM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_radio_band)) equipment ([Part 18](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/part-18)) in the US must be type-accepted by the FCC.  That means that the manufacturer must apply to have the radio tested and certified by the FCC as being acceptable according to the laws that govern the applicable radio service.  Baofeng/Pofung radios designed for the ham market, such as the UV-82, have never been legally able to transmit on public safety bands (or [FRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Radio_Service) or [GMRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Mobile_Radio_Service) bands).  People cheerfully imported them anyway by the hundreds of thousands.

On 24 September 2018, the FCC published an [Enforcement Advisory](https://docs.fcc.gov/public/attachments/DA-18-980A1.pdf) that says, right at the top of the first page: "**Two-way VHF/UHF radios may not be imported, advertised, or sold in the United States unless they comply with the Commission’s rules.**"  (I changed the case, made the text bold, and added a period at the end.)  This message was obviously aimed squarely at importers of Baofeng/Pofung and other similar Chinese radios who had been ignoring the law.  The importers and the manufacturers seem to have received the message loud and clear, because new Baofeng/Pofung radios sold in the US can no longer transmit on public safety, FRS, or GMRS bands.

Comment: I bought a UV-82 after you made this post and can still transmit on FRS (which makes sense because no license is required).